# Indexing server with meta tags

Tags: indexing, meta-tags

I would like to add <**meta name="description" content="....."**/> to the html pages for indexing server to pick it up.
I got the property "description" in indexing server, but I don't know how to write the query to select it.

**select description from scope() where ......,** but it is not working, error message is "DESCRIPTION IS NOT DEFINED".

I need your help.

Thanks
Tony

P.S. I am using WINDOW 2003 R2

Comment: I would recommend making 1 of the 5 allowed tags on your posting to be windows-search. When you say 'for indexing server or window search service', are they both part of the windows-search service? Good luck!

Comment: Shelter: thank you. Since I haven't found any documentation about meta tags in window search service, I have to use Indexing Server instead.

Comment: after adding the FriendlyNamesDefinitionFile.txt to C:\WINDOWS\system32 and update the DefaultColumnFile value under ContentIndexCommon key, it is working now. But still cannot find any documentation about it. My stations is Window 2003 Server(64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

after adding the FriendlyNamesDefinitionFile.txt to C:\WINDOWS\system32 and update the DefaultColumnFile value under ContentIndexCommon key, it is working now. But still cannot find any documentation about it. My stations is Window 2003 Server(64 bit). Grant the correct permission to the folder where the files are.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than searching for 'description', you might want to try searching for 'characterization' instead. This worked for me -- with the bizarre caveat that the order of the attribute values on your `<meta>` tags has to be `name`, then `content` (I tried the other way around and the search stopped working).

I agree that the lack of documentation on the Windows Indexing Server is quite frustrating.